# Archive a devops project

Tags: azure-devops

I've got 2 projects, one of which is phased out and replaced by the other.
The legacy project will be deleted in due time, but for now we want to keep it alive but discourage develops from accidentally working on the legacy project.

Github<sup>1</sup> & Gitlab<sup>2</sup> allows you to archive your repository, is there such an option available for azure devops?

1 https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/archiving-a-github-repository/archiving-repositories

2 https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/#archive-a-project

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no way to archive a project currently. Your best option to stop people working on it by mistake would be to alter their permissions to limit what they can do

Comment: this should be marked as answer